# Styling UILabel's through whole app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Im developing an application with multiple `UIViewControllers` containing UILabel components. Alot of `UIViewControllers` have the same setup a title, subtitle, subtext and/or text. In every `UIViewControllers` I kept changing the font-size, color and more variables so i wanted to use something like a style for all the `UIView` components so all the changes effect all the components in all the ViewControllers.

I created custom `UILabel` classes and linked it in my storyboards with the custom class that implementing default style. But it is not working properly.

```
class UICustomLabel: UILabel 
{
  override func layoutSubviews()
  {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.font = UIFont(name: Style.FontNameDefault, size: Style.FontSizeDefault);
  }
}

class UILabelTitle: UILabel 
{
  override func layoutSubviews()
  {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.font = UIFont(name: Style.FontNameTitle, size: Style.FontSizeTitle);
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to style all the UIView components through your whole app the same way?

Comment: You should set the font in the constructor, this will then be called once the label is created. Now the font is called every time the layout changes.

Comment: Oke and if i fix that is this the way to go or is there a better solution for styling all UILabel's in multiple ViewControllers?

Comment: Well that is a matter of opinion, you could use [`UIAppearance proxy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html) or set the font in the `loadView` of each controller. This is really up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an extension on `UILabel` that provides a number of factory methods for all label types you need.

```
extension UILabel {
    class func stl_titleLabel() -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = ...
        return label
    }
    class func stl_commentLabel(frame: CGRect, color: UIColor) -> UILabel { // whatever arguments you need
        let label = UILabel(frame)
        label.font = ...
        label.textColor = color
        return label
    } 
}
```

There are can be some syntax errors in code since I'm not that good with swift, but i think you get the idea. I'm hoping it helps.

EDIT: Oops, I missed that you use storyboards. My solution would work if labels were created with code. Maybe there is a way to combine it with storyboards, but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I find this libraries very useful:

[NUI](https://github.com/tombenner/nui),
[Motif](https://github.com/erichoracek/Motif).

It's like CSS for iOS.

But if you are looking for pure iOS solution, try to set your font properties in `awakeFromNib` or in `init` instead of `layoutSubviews`. Also make sure that your `IBOutlets` in ViewControllers have correct declarations (e.g. `UITitleLabel` instead of `UILabel`)

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in way to achieve this - it is called `UIAppearance`. This protocol is implemented by all system views. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html)

And a small example :

```
[[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyCustomView class]] setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]]
```

Sorry for example in Obj-C, this is also avaiable in Swift.

The first line sets the text color for all `UILabels` to white. The second line makes the text color blue, but only if the `UILabel` is a subview of a `MyCustomView`. This way you can easily add exceptions from a general rule, if there are any.

Also, note that the effects will take effect for `UILabels` added after running this code, so the best place for this is propably in the `AppDelegate`.